# How to use embedded jetty with maven overlays

Tags: java, maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm writing extension to java web application. I add this application to my extension with maven overlay plugin and use web.xml file and webapp folder from main application. 
Also I want to write integration test platform for my extension with jetty embedded server.
I've tried

```
    @Test
public void jetty() throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(9090);
    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setDescriptor("WEB-INF/web.xml");
    context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

But jetty can't find web.xml file from overlayed project. How i need to write the path to web.xml and webapp directory to make embbedded jetty work?

Answer (score 0):

I have given the full path and works perfectly for me, something like this:

context.setDescriptor("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");